# symfony 2.7.5 : homepage link does not work when using other controller

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm creating a website with symfony 2.7.5. 
I have a menu bar that is the same for all pages, so I included it into base.html.twig, than the other views can inherit from it.

In this menu bar, I have a link to the home page. And here is the problem : when I open this link from a view contained at the root directory, no problem. But When I open this link from a subfolder view, the link is automatically overwritten with FOLDER NAME/HOMEPAGE link.

So how can I have an homepage link working from every place of my website ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using relative paths. A path function is available in Twig to generate the correct urls.

Here is the relative information in the SF2 docs:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-pages

Comment: Just perfect ! Thank you for the link. It works fine.

Comment: Would you advise to create a new controller for every sub section of my site ?

Comment: You should if they have logic inside. If you have some static pages that do not require any logic(about, term & cons, etc), you can group them in a controller and then pass a slug to the url know which template is requested.